# C function imported in python gives meaningless output - translation mishap?

Tags: python, c

I am translating some code from C to Python 3, and checking that the functions give the correct output.

In the manual for the C code, this is what it says for the `pb_get_version()` function:

[image]

I then try to implement this in Python. I load the DLL, define the function, and print its output.

```
import ctypes

spinapi = ctypes.CDLL("spinapi64")
pb_get_version = spinapi.pb_get_version

version = pb_get_version()
print("Using SpinAPI Library version {}".format(version))

% Using SpinAPI Library version 331435824
```

The output is not in the YYYMMDD as I expect it...

Could this be a translation error from the DLL (C) to Python? Is there a simple way to translate `char*` to python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `ctypes` assumes that the function returns an `int`. You must specify that the function returns a `char*` for it to work. Try the following before calling the function:

```
pb_get_version.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
```